# Let p be a prime number and G a cyclic group of order 2p.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let p be a prime number and G a cyclic group of order 2p. What are the elements of order p in G?

Since |G| = 2p then is this just 2p/p = 2 elements of order p?

Answer (score 0):

In any cyclic group of order $m$ there are, for $n\mid m$ exactly $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$. For $m=2p$ and $n=p$ we have $\phi(p)=p-1$. So only for $p=3$ we have exactly $2$ elements of order $p=3$ in the cyclic group $C_{2p}=C_6$.